# ID Token in Resource Owner Password Grant in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have implemented IdentityServer 4 in a .Net Core API project.

I created a `Resource Owner Credentials Grant` client and allowed openID scopes.

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
.AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients).
AddResourceOwnerValidator<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Here's my client code:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "resourceownerclient",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    Enabled = true,
    ClientSecrets=  new List<Secret> { new Secret("Secret".Sha256()) },
    AllowedScopes = {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "api1"
    }
}
```

I have also added all the scopes in AddInMemoryIdentityResources().

But the response does not contain ID token.

```
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImt",
"expires_in": 3600,
"token_type": "Bearer",
"scope": "api1 openid"
}
```

Looked at the other question on the SO on whether the Open ID Connect supports the Resource Owner Credentials Grant.

**How can I get ID token in the response?**

The refresh token call returns ID token but it's a [bug](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3621).

Comment: The same question has been already asked at this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421160/how-to-get-id-token-along-with-access-token-from-identityserver4-via-password?rq=1). The short answer is No because **Resource Owner Password Credentials flow** provides only access tokens.